# How to define a global struct which uses namespace so that files which use the struct do not use this namespace? c++

Tags: c++, struct, namespaces

I have a `common_module.h` file which should store structures and functions used by most of .cpp files.

I want it to have an `RColor` struct.

RColor uses a lot of functions and variables from namespace cv. The project is made in a way that .cpp files generally do **not** use cv namespace (All work with it is mostly done by structures like `RColor`)

I don't want to always write `cv::something` in definition of `RColor`. So i tried to create an `RColor` prototype in `common_module.h` and put it definition to  `Rcolor.cpp`:

```
//common_module.h
//...
struct RColor;
```

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
struct RColor
{
    ...
};
```

---

```
//Project0.cpp (main file)
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<windows.h>
RColor col;
```

---

I get error:

```
1>error C2079: 'col' uses undefined struct 'RColor'
```

Comment: If I put it in a header, how can I use this header without adding `using namespace cv;` to all files which use it?

Comment: `struct RColor
{
 using namespace cv;
};` produces `error C2059: syntax error : 'namespace'` `error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'`

Comment: As for your error, you need the full definition of a structure to create an instance of it.

Comment: I cannot, can I? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326805/why-using-namespace-x-is-not-allowed-inside-class-struct-level

Comment: @Angew I though drinking coffee would prevent these brain farts, but obviously not :-)

Comment: Are you using so much things from the `cv` namespace, that writing four extra characters every time is such a hassle? Besides, it will make the code more clear and readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error because code using `RColor` needs to see its definition, not just its declaration. You'll have to move the definition to the header.

As to how to deal with the namespace `cv`, you write:

> I don't want to always write `cv::something` in definition of `RColor`.

The correct response to this is "don't be lazy, write it." Explicit qualification is good, that's what namespaces are for. At least in the class definition itself, you have no way around it<sup>(*)</sup> - you want to prevent the identifiers from `cv` from polluting the global namespace. Note that it also makes the code more self-documenting: `cv::transform` tells a reader way more about the type or function than just `transform` does (is the latter `cv::transform` or `std::transform` or ...?)

If you *really* want and need to save on typing `cv::` inside member functions of `RColor`, you can put `using namespace cv;` inside the member function definitions. But I wouldn't do even that.

---

(*) There *is* actually a way to achieve what you want, but it's quite hacky (and would never pass code review with me). But out of a sense of completeness, here goes:

```
// common_module.h

namespace NobodyTryToUseThisName
{
  using namespace cv;

  struct RColor
  {
    // ... definition here
  };
}

using NobodyTryToUseThisName::RColor;
```

But as I say, I **do not recommend** doing this.