# Why can I not use the namespace directive in c++ struct?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scoped using-directive within a struct/class declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362831/scoped-using-directive-within-a-struct-class-declaration)
>   [Why “using namespace X;” is not allowed inside class/struct level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326805/why-using-namespace-x-is-not-allowed-inside-class-struct-level)

I would like to introduce only std::string into structure. 
Why is the below considered illegal?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Father
{
    using std::string;

    string sons[20];
    string daughters[20];
};
```

But oddly enough, i can do the following the in a function

```
int main()
{
    using std::string;
}
```

Update: C++ uses the same keyword with different semantics.

c++ uses the keyword "using" to introduce a data member or function from the base class into the current class. Thus when i wrote using std::string inside a struct declaration, compiler is assuming that i am trying to introduce a member from a base class std. But std is not a base class, rather it is a namespace.
Thus

```
struct A
{
     int i;
}

struct B:A
{
     using A::i; // legal
     using std::string// illegal, because ::std is not a class
}
```

the same "using" keyword is also used to access a member of a particular namespace.

So, i am guessing compiler decides the semantics of "using" based on where it is declared.

Comment: Please **do not** remove the automatically inserted "possible duplicate" link when you edit the question. I understand that you updated in order to explain why you think it's *not* a duplicate of the suggested question, and that's perfectly acceptable/encouraged behavior. But you should either let your edits bump up the question and attract re-open votes from users who notice it in the list, or use the "flag" link to ask a moderator to examine and re-open it as per your updates. Removing the automatically inserted link is very strongly discouraged; the system will remove it upon reopening.

Comment: (If removing it was an accident in this case—i.e., your edits collided in time—then I apologize for the harsh-sounding tone. Just take it as good advice for the future! :-))

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to your actual question, but you can use a typedef:

```
struct Father
{
    typedef std::string string;

    string sons[20];
    string daughters[20];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just not allowed by the language unfortunately, but there's a workaround:

```
namespace Father_Local
{
    using std::string;

    struct Father
    {
        //...
    };
}

using Father_Local::Father;
```

The advantage of this approach is that you could in principle write a using directive e.g.

```
using namespace boost::multi_index;
```

there and save yourself a load of typing and clutter in a header file. None of this affects the rest of the code - Father gets imported into its proper namespace by the using at the end and everything works fine.