# "Using" declaration with scope only on current class?

Tags: c++, c++11, using, using-directives

Is there a possibility to have a `using` directive whose scope is limited to a single class?

Note, that what I want to "use" is not contained in the parent of the current class.

For simplicity, assume the following exmple:

```
#include<vector>

class foo
{
using std::vector; //Error, a class-qualified name is required
}
```

Another interesting thing to know is, if the `using` directives are included, if a header is included:

```
MyClassFoo.h:
#include<vector>

using std::vector; //OK
class foo
{

}
```

And in

```
NewHeader.h
#include "MyClassFoo.h"
...
```

how can I prevent "`using std::vector`" to be visible here?

Comment: Is there a possibility to create a templated type alias for "std::vector<T>" that is then called "vector"? That way it'd do the same as what I want the using std::vector to do inside the class

Comment: Yes, `using` declarations can be templated when creating type aliases, and it's okay to call that type alias `vector` since it's in another scope from `std::vector`.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that this isn't a *using directive*, it's a *using declaration*. Using directives introduce **namespaces**.

Comment: thanks, and I changed the "directive" to "declaration"

Comment: Close to what you want using a [wrapper namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4363431/86967).

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged c++11:

```
#include<vector>

class foo
{
  template<typename T>
  using vector = std::vector<T>;
};
```

Comment: Also, `template<class T, class... Args> using vector = std::vector<T, Args...>;` if you ever have *any* inclination of using the optional allocator.

Comment: This looks, good, but unfortunately it gives me "unrecognizable template declaration/definition"?!

Comment: @S.H You need to compile with -std=c++11 with a recent enough compiler

Comment: Since I'm compiling with C++11, it's a problem of VS2012 -> [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) to supported VS C++11 features

Comment: @S.H Yep seems it was introduced in VS2013: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn467695.aspx, sad =/

Answer (score 0):

As for your first requirement, you can use a namespace so that the scope of `using namespace` is limited to a single class.

```
#include<vector>

namespace FooClasses
{
    using namespace std; //The scope of this statement will NOT go outside this namespace.

    class foo
    {
      vector<int> vecIntVector; 
    };

}// namespace FooClasses
```

For your second case, do make use of `#define` and `#undef` wisely.